# Prevent pacman from reinstalling packages that were already installed

Tags: linux, package-management

How to prevent pacman (archlinux's package manager) from reinstalling packages that were already installed?

```
 pacman -S packagename    # install and reinstall if exists
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use the `--needed` option to skip reinstall of existing packages when you Sync (-S).

> If a package in the list is already installed on the system, it will be reinstalled even if it is already up to date. *This behavior can be overridden with the --needed option.*

- [Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Installing_package_groups)
- [More info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Tips#Backing_up_and_retrieving_a_list_of_installed_packages)